# I want to create an html document in flutter and copy it to the clipboard. What should I do?

Tags: html, flutter

I want to create an html document in flutter and copy it to the clipboard. What should I do?

**Example> Clipboard value:**

```
<video style="width:100%; max-width:900px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6CRz23A6Gw" controls="controls" loop="loop" muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay"></video>'
                           '<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/category/fashion/900x600" /><br />
```

**Code:**

```
  var document = parse(
                      '<video style="width:100%; max-width:900px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6CRz23A6Gw" controls="controls" loop="loop" muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay"></video>'
                      '<img src="${_smartPage.header!.imageUrl}" /><br />');
                  print('html:${document.toString()}');
                  Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: document.toString()));
```

Comment: Copy html to clipboard as raw code?

Comment: Yes, it is. I want to copy the raw code to the clipboard.

Comment: Check https://pub.dev/packages/clipboard

Answer (score 0):

You can use flutter_html package to draw your html codes on the screen. Sample using;

```
String myHtmlCode= "<h1>This is Sample </h1>";
    Container(
    child: Html(
    data:myHtmlCode,),
    )
```

Then you can use clipboard package to copy your String to clipboard.

```
FlutterClipboard.copy(myHtmlCode).then(( value ) =>
                              print('copied'));
```